# Python : Sum of numbers in different files

Tags: python, file, sum

I know it seems my problem already has a solution but it's not quite what I need in the other subjects. So here is it:
I have 200 files where each file has 800 lines. Each line of a file contains 800 numbers. In short, each file has exactly the same format. Let's say, to make it simple, that my files are something like that:

File 1:

> 28 56 72 50 01
>   65 41 20 18 00

File 2:

> 01 32 09 05 42
>   00 23 14 52 99

What I need to do is, the sum of the numbers placed at the same location in the files, meaning that I need an output file like that:

Output:

> 29 88 81 55 43
>   65 64 34 70 99

For now, what I wanted to do is write each line in different files but it would take so much place...

I'm not sure how I can do that. If anyone has any suggestion, I'm open to it. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you know the file format beforehand and have a list of file names, you just iterate over the files and accumulate the sums in a list of lists of the right size:

```
nrows, ncols = 2, 5          # 800, 800 in your real code
sums = [[0] * ncols for _ in range(nrows)]

file_names = ["file1.txt", "file2.txt"]
for file_name in file_names:
    with open(file_name) as f:
        for i, row in enumerate(f):
            for j, col in enumerate(row.split()):
                sums[i][j] += int(col)

for row in sums:
    print(*row)
# 29 88 81 55 43
# 65 64 34 70 99
```

---

Alternatively using [`numpy.loadtxt`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.loadtxt.html):

```
import numpy as np

sum(np.loadtxt(file_name, dtype=int) for file_name in file_names)
# array([[ 29,  88,  81,  55,  43],
#        [ 65,  64,  34,  70,  99]])
```

Comment: Thank you, it worked perfectly. Another question: what if each line begins with a string and then numbers?

Comment: @Peter Then the `numpy` version does not work anymore (but there is `numpy.genfromtxt` IIRC, it is mentioned in the doc I linked above under See Also). In any case, it depends, is it always the same string, is there a separator between the string and the numbers, does the string contain spaces, does it follow some regular structure, does it have a specific length?

Comment: @Peter: Then the easiest way is to replace `for j, col in enumerate(row.split()):` with `for j, col in enumerate(row[k:].split()):`, where `k` is the index of the first character of the first numerical value (i.e. for the case `foo: 28 56 72 50 01`, `k = 5`) or `for j, col in enumerate(row.split()[1:]):` if there is a space between the string and the first value.

Comment: Thanks a lot, your solution is exactly what I needed

Answer (score 3):

First you can load a single file, in order to get the strucure of the file(s). This will also handel the case where not all rows have the same number of observations. Then based on the structure you itterate over all files and rows in order to add the single values.

```
further_files = ['file 2']
sums = []
with open('file 1') as file:
    for row in file:
        sums.append(row.split())

for file in further_files:
    with open(file) as open_file:
        for i, row in enumerate(open_file):
            sums[i] = [x + y for x, y in zip(sums[i], row.split())]
```

Comment: you get this error when I run your code: `NameError: name 'further_files' is not defined`

Comment: yes, you need to define further_files, as the list of furter_files you want to read.

Answer (score 2):

Using `numpy`

**Ex:**

```
import os
import numpy as np


result = {}
base_path = r"PATH_TO_FILES"
for filename in os.listdir(base_path):               #Iterate each file
    filename = os.path.join(base_path, filename)
    with open(filename) as infile:                   #Open file for read
        for i, line in enumerate(infile):
            if i not in result:
                result[i] = np.array(line.split(), dtype=int)
            else:
                result[i] = result[i] + np.array(line.split(), dtype=int)    #sum lines

for k, v in result.items():
    print(v)
```

**Output:**

```
[29 88 81 55 43]
[65 64 34 70 99]
```