# How can I sum integers from multiple text files into a new text file using python?

Tags: python, sum, text-files

I am currently trying to take ten different text files (file2_0.txt, file2_1.txt,file2_2.txt,...) all containing one column and one hundred million rows of random integers and add the text files row by row. I want to add every row from all ten files together and generate a new text file (total_file.txt) with the sum of each row. Below is an example of what I am trying to do using two of the files added together to create total_file.txt.

file2_0.txt

```
5
19
51
10
756
```

file2_1.txt

```
11
43
845
43
156
```

total_file.txt

```
16
62
896
53
912
```

Since these files are rather large I am not trying to read them into memory and instead use concurrency. I found sample code from another StackOverflow ([Python : Sum of numbers in different files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55570357/python-sum-of-numbers-in-different-files)) question that I was trying before doing all of the files at one time. The problem I am having is that the output (total_file.txt) only contains the numbers from the second text file (file2_1.txt) with nothing added.  I am not sure why this is.  I am new to Stackoverflow and coding in general and wanted to ask about this on the linked post, however, I read online that is not good practice.  Below is the code I worked on.

```
import shutil
#Files to add
filenames = ['file2_0.txt', 'file2_1.txt']`
sums = []

with open('file2_0.txt') as file:
    for row in file:
        sums.append(row.split())
#Create output file
with open('total_file.txt', 'wb') as wfd:
    for file in filenames:
        with open(file) as open_file:
            for i, row in enumerate(open_file):
                sums[i] = sums[i]+row.split()

    with open(file, 'rb') as fd:
        shutil.copyfileobj(fd, wfd)
```

Just for background, I am working with these large files to test processing speeds. Once I get an understanding of what I am doing wrong I will be working on parallel processing specifically multithreading to test the various process speeds.  Please let me know what further information you might need from me.

Comment: To be clear, you want to add the elements line-wise? So the number on the first line of the first file gets added to the number on the first line of the second file, to create the first line of the output? You should start by trying to explain your intended algorithm, step by step, in plain English words. Consider taking a real pencil and sheet of paper and drawing a flowchart.

Comment: Anyway, I don't understand what you expect `shutil.copyfileobj(fd, wfd)` to do, or how many times you expect it to happen. I also don't understand what you expect `row.split()` to do, or what you expect `sums` to look like after the first loop - you should start by checking that. Among other things, you seem to be under the impression that the contents of the file will become integers simply because they "look right". This is not the case.

Comment: Basically, there are too many problems here to explain it to you simply. You should start by trying to write code that solves a simpler, but related problem. For example, try to handle *one* file and make sure you can create a *correct* list *of integers* from it. From there you should make sure you are making use of *functions* to organize your code properly.

Comment: Yes. I am taking each text file and adding every row together so that the final text file has the sum of every row from all ten text files as seen in the example above. I want to keep every row in only one column.  I used shutil.copyfileobj to copy and combine files previously, but it seems that this might not be the best method now?  As I have said I am new to python and trying to learn and understand.  The problem that I am having is adding each row and iterating through the files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd use generators so you don't have to load all of the files into memory at once (in case they're large)

Then just pull the next value from each generator, sum them, write them and carry on. When you hit the end of the file you'll get a StopIteration exception and be done

```py
def read_file(file):
  with open(file, "r") as inFile:
    for row in inFile:
      yield row

file_list = ["file1.txt", "file2.txt", ..., "file10.txt"]
file_generators = [read_file(path) for path in file_list]

with open("totals.txt", "w+") as outFile:
  while True
    try:
      outFile.write(f"{sum([int(next(gen)) for gen in file_generators])}\n")
    except StopIteration:
      break
```

Comment: I am getting the following error: TypeError: write() argument must be str, not int. This error is referencing outFile.write(sum([int(next(gen)) for gen in file_generators])).

Comment: updated, wrapped the outFile and added a newline; I haven't tested this code -- if you end up with spaces between each line in the output fil we can just remove the `\n`

Comment: That was it. I will do some research on generators as I am not very familiar with them and have been using chunking. I am sorry that I cannot give you an upvote yet.  I will once I have enough reputation.

Comment: generators are great, they're functions that `yield` instead of `return` -- one great use for them is let's say you wanted to apply 3 functions to each item in a list, in order instead of looping over the list 3 times or creating a massive do everything function the first generator can perform it's operation and yield to the next and so on -- think of it as a pipe that data flows through

Comment: The file streaming piece is nice because it moves a pointer across the file instead of loading the whole file into memory -- this is very useful for handling many large files